# Ways to get the value of mapping public?

Tags: solidity

I have this piece of code, but I dont have implemented a view returns function.

```
mapping (uint256 => TokenTimeLockInfo) public locks;
struct TokenTimeLockInfo {
    Token token;
    address beneficiary;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 unlockTime;
}
```

I can access the value way **web3js** are possible?

Or do I need **another contract to implement a view returns**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the property is public, you can access it using the getter function automatically generated by Solidity compiler.

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, contractAddress);

// returns value of the mapping for the key `0`
const info = await myContract.methods.locks(0).call();
```

Docs:

- https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/contracts.html#getter-functions
- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Perfect!